# LShift key reading as pressed continuously

Tags: laptop, keyboard

My laptop is an HP Pavilion, Model 15-n293cl.  The keyboard's Left Shift key is acting, intermittently, as though it is continuously pressed.  This is the third occurrence of this problem.  As I type this, it seems to be behaving itself; whether this is because of the external keyboard I am using, or because it is finished with its current 'fit', I do not know.  So forgive me if I suddenly start using all capitals; it is not yelling, but rather another occurrence of the problem, mid-writing.
Currently, I have "disabled" the Left Shift key itself by removing the springs and the "depressor" (which, I admit, was originally held in place by adhesive).  This does nothing to alleviate the problem.  Further, the external keyboard workaround, which was not employed during the previous occurrences, is not perfect; occasionally, the problem will reassert itself; that is, it will override the external keyboard's signals.
I am sure I do not need to explain how severely this problem affects the usage of my computer.  The Shift keys are used for a vast multitude of functions.  Their primary usage, accessing alternate symbols on the keyboard, becomes a particular problem - especially if one is trying to enter one's password to log in.

Comment: If this is a Windows OS, have you checked to see if Sticky Keys are enabled and incorrectly configured?

Comment: It is indeed a Windows OS.  However, Sticky Keys are not enabled.